# Catch a word into quotes using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I have a string with many caracters and I need obtain data from it.
First of all, I did explode by ';', now I have an array and of each row I have a word into quotes.

I want to remove all, less this word into quotes. I know that is more easy to obtain these words with preg_match, but how is into an array, to save up to go over the array again, I would like to clean it directly with preg_replace.

```
$array = explode(';', $string);

//36 => string 's:7:"trans_1"' (length=13)
//37 => string 's:3:"104"' (length=9)
//38 => string 's:5:"addup"' (length=11)
//39 => string 's:1:"0"' (length=7)

$array = preg_replace('!   !i', '', $array);
```

I would like to obtain:

```
//36 => string 'trans_1' (length=6)
//37 => string '104' (length=3)
//38 => string 'addup' (length=5)
//39 => string '0' (length=1)
```

I tryed differents things, but I can't rid off the letters outside the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this isn't a direct answer to your question it solves your problem. The data you are looking at came from the php function `serialize()` to retrieve the data from that string you need to use the php function `unserialize()`.

```
$data = unserialize($string);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
preg_replace('!.*"([^"]*)".*!i', '\1', $array);
```

`\1` refers to the first captured group!

Comment: You could probably even use preg_match to avoid having to explode the string in the first case

Comment: @sebasparola Also could you just `unserialize()` the data? It looks like you're trying to parse data that came from the php function `serialize()`

Comment: @chrislondon wow you are right, unserialize() works without have to use a regexp, saved my life jej. Should I do some comment about this in somewhere??